# Ignore .DS_Store files when using esbuild

Tags: macos, esbuild

When using esbuild on a macOS filesystem, there might be `.DS_Store` files (which contain Finder metadata) in or below one of the entry points which end up in the bundle. Now, there seems to be an ignore arg on the esbuild CLI tool, but since my asset bundling is baked into the framework, I have to find a solution using `esbuildOptions`.

There's the obvious solution of writing a plugin, but maybe someone has come up with a simpler solution?